# AND/IF/MIN - Function excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find the min value of something from table based on three criterias.

I have tried the following without any succes:

```
=MIN(IF(AND(Table[Letter]="F";Table[Level]=A2;Table[Title]]=B2");Table[Amount];"-"))
```

There should be a value based on these three criterias but I'm getting nothing.

Table is a table found in another worksheet

Comment: do you really have two tables `Table` and `Table5` or is that a typo?

Comment: typo! Any ideas?

Comment: If you type `=MINIFS(A:A, A:A, 1)` into your worksheet do you get a #NAME? error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want the `"-"` to show up in case no row matches the criteria, otherwise show the minimum matching amount. The best way to achieve this is by using the `AGGREGATE` function (Excel 2010+):

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 6, Table[Amount] / (Table[Letter]="F") /
   (Table[Level]=A2) / (Table[Title]=B2), 1), "-")
```

p.s.: change the commas `,` to semi-colons `;` to adapt it to your locale.

Comment: I tried using your function but it is only return "-".

Comment: @MarounNasr this formula has been tested intensively. Check table and field names, and that there **are** some rows that match `Letter="F" and
   Level=A2 and Title=B2 and some amount`. And here I mean the data entered in cells A2 and B2, not explicit text "A2" and "B2".

Comment: If I write Level = 10 the functon works but if I write Level=A2 where A2=10 it does not.

Comment: what is the format of the `Level` column and of the **cell `A2`**? Because you might be comparing text in `A2` to number in Level. And just for info, \are you typing the formula in the same ws containing the table?

Comment: @MarounNasr In all cases that means that the formula works. What remains is to check the dta, cell formats etc.

Comment: I really apperciate all your help. Thank you very much!!